# reading from ppm file error access violating reading location

Tags: c++

im doing assignment where i read from ppm file and change color values, im having issues reading the file.
I have an exception thrown, it says reading invalid data from board.

```
        cout << "Read input called" << endl;
        board = new int* [numcols];
        for (int i = 0; i < numcols; i++) {
            board[i] = new int[numrows];
        }

        string line;
        char header[3];

        infile >> header;
        getline(infile, line);
        getline(infile, line);
        infile >> numcols >> numrows >> max;

        for (int i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numcols; j++) {
                infile >> board[j][i] >> board[j][i+1] >> board[j][i+2]; //exception thrown here
            }
        }
```

Comment: You create `board` before you read `numcols` and `numrows` so presumably `board` isn't the same size as the file. `header` is also probably too small, use `std::string` instead. Please show a [mre]

Comment: Read numcols before allocating your memory and try not to use new/delete, use `std::vector<int>` for  `board`. And use `std::string` for `header` to protect you against files with more then 3 characters in its header (never trust your input).

Comment: `board[j][i+1]` -- This is an out-of-bounds access on the last iteration of the `for i` loop.